# Удалить из строки все пробелы в c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Я новичок в c++, и есть задача удалить все лишние пробелы из строки, не используя дополнительную строку. Можно использовать функцию erase(), но вопрос, использует ли эта функция дополнительную строку внутри себя? Если да, то как можно удалить лишние пробелы по другому?

Comment: Что такое "лишний пробел"? Строка это `const char[]` или `std::string` или что-то ещё? Реализация стандартных функций не оговаривается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто идете по строке с двумя указателями и копируете непробельные символы.

Примерно так (для С-строки):

```
char * rspace(char * s)
{
    char * from = s, *to = s;
    do {
        if (*from != ' ') *to++ = *from;
    } while(*++from);
    *to = 0;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Test string for space removing";
    cout << rspace(s) << endl;
}
```

Для C++-строки - аналогично:

```
string& rspace(string& s)
{
    char * from = s.data(), *to = s.data();
    do {
        if (*from != ' ') *to++ = *from;
    } while(*++from);
    s.resize(to-s.data());
    return s;
}
```

Так вы гарантированно докажете преподу, что никакая другая строка не используется :)